# How to achieve a perspective where two axes of a 3D scene coincide with the x and y axes of the 2D projection?

Tags: 3d, asymptote

[image: axes sketch]

How should the corresponding camera line look like?

```
currentprojection = orthographic(camera=(x,y,z),up=Y,target=O);
```

In particular, I need a formula for the triple (x,y,z) depending on the angle between the x and y axes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is called "oblique" projection. As explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection.

**You need to use `currentprojection=oblique;` to achieve this kind of projection**.

First two examples from the gallery:

http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/planes.asy

http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/.cache/planes.png

Now the code:

```
import three;
import graph3;
currentprojection=obliqueX(-45); // angle in degrees for the third axis (e.g. 25)
size(5cm);
xaxis3("$x$",0,1,black);
yaxis3("$y$",0,1,black);
zaxis3("$z$",0,1,black);
viewportsize=(345.0pt,0);
```

[image: obliquexyz]

(BTW, I couldn't make the sign of the angle argument of `obliqueZ` or `obliqueX` to make the "x" axis to stick to left-top direction.)

and just to illustrate that is **not** possible to get this with other projections,

```
...
currentprojection=orthographic(4,6,3);
...
```

[image: orthoxyz]

Comment: Oblique projection distorts the image in an unrealistic way. Is it possible to get the axes as shown, but still use an orthographic or perspective projection?

Comment: @Jan, "Oblique projection distorts the image in an unrealistic way", ok, I know, and still is what you want from the example image (maybe without knowing). You can't get that result and use orthographic projection, sorry. If the axis "y" and "z" have the same 3D length in your image and the 2D projection is 90 degree the this has to be `oblique` projection.

Comment: I'm still curious, whether it is possible to find a camera position, which yields the following: The orientation of the axes is as shown with a right angle between z and y and some angle between x and y. I do not require the axes to have a particular length in the projection. They may appear shortened as required by the perspective.

Comment: @Jan, no, it is impossible. Think about it, if you are looking directly at the y-z plane (like in your example), how can you see the x axis "sticking" out to a side? This is not possible in orthogonal projection. I recommend this book http://www.amazon.com/Extreme-Perspective-For-Artists-Curvilinear/dp/0823026655

Comment: @alfC: It would be possible to do with a perspective projection, though, by zooming out really far and moving the camera to the left while still looking in the x direction.

Comment: @Jake, even in that case the "x" vector (versor) in the example won't have the same 2D projected length as "z" and "y", and between "z" and "y". The trick of zooming out very far is, in any case, the same as orthogonal projection, so there is no gain in doing that.

Comment: @alfC: Zooming out to "infinity" is the same as orthogonal projection, but moving very far to the left so you can "see the side of the box out of the corner of your eye" is not. But yeah, you're right about the length of the x vector not having the same length, I missed that bit.